# How to sign my testapp in android?

Tags: android

I am new to Robotium Testing. I have read that "The apk file must have the same certificate signature that your test project has".

How to sign my test project?

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to sign your app so you can upload it to the Android Market... is that right?

[Here](http://mussharapp.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-your-android-market-ready-apk.html) is a step by step instruction on how to sign your apk file to make it Android Market ready

Comment: Hi, I dont want to upload my app in to Market. Actually i have .apk file only (No source code). I want to test this with Robotium. This is my req.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this wiki page for more information:

http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles